# Random number generator in parallel computing (MATLAB), different initial random numbers in every parallel loop?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, parallel-processing, parfor

Suppose that I have this code in MATLAB:

```
% Predefined data
SX = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    parfor xx = 1:4
        naming2 = SX(xx);
        [BestM, BestX{xx},  fina_M{xx}, final_D{xx}, BestAA{xx}, final_Data{xx}] = Optmz(naming2,  v_data); 
    end
```

`Optmz` is an optimization algorithm. This optimization algorithm should run to optimize a regression model (with different output and optimized inputs-feature selection). As you know heuristic optimization algorithms are based on random numbers. We have different initial random numbers in every `parlor` loop? Is this a proper structure to decrease time of my application? I'm currently using `for` loop in above structure.

This is a part of printed output. Iterations are not sorted. Any problem? Based on above code we should have four iterations with same number. I need total different calculations in all 4 workers with different initial random number generator. For example, like the way we run our calculations in sequence without parallel computing. Run first one, second one, third one and finally fourth one.

```
******Iteration 24,   Best Cost = 0.041201******
******Iteration 26,   Best Cost = 0.034994******
******Iteration 26,   Best Cost = 0.036624******
******Iteration 26,   Best Cost = 0.039317******
******Iteration 25,   Best Cost = 0.039584******
******Iteration 27,   Best Cost = 0.034994******
******Iteration 27,   Best Cost = 0.036624******
******Iteration 27,   Best Cost = 0.039317******
******Iteration 28,   Best Cost = 0.034994******
******Iteration 26,   Best Cost = 0.039242******
******Iteration 28,   Best Cost = 0.036624******
******Iteration 28,   Best Cost = 0.03931******
******Iteration 29,   Best Cost = 0.034994******
******Iteration 29,   Best Cost = 0.036624******
******Iteration 27,   Best Cost = 0.039048******
******Iteration 29,   Best Cost = 0.03931******
******Iteration 30,   Best Cost = 0.034994******
******Iteration 30,   Best Cost = 0.036624******
******Iteration 28,   Best Cost = 0.039048******
```

Comment: @MZimmerman6 We have different initial random numbers in every parlor loop? Is this a proper structure to decrease time of my application? Iterations are not sorted. Any problem?

Comment: In `parfor` loops, the accessed indices are never guaranteed to be in order.  Guaranteeing order and parallelization is usually an oxymoron.

Comment: If you are asking if it is okay for the iterations to be out of order, then, as @rayryeng said, it is almost impossible to guarantee any sort of order. Because of this, your code has to be designed to not care if things are not done in a specific order.

Comment: thank you for both comments. The second question is about random numbers in my optimization algorithm (here I'm using genetic algorithm). We need have same random number generator with same initial condition in every worker? I'm predicting 4 different outputs in every worker. Suppose that it is high temperature, low temperature, median temperature and mean temperature of a system.

Comment: @user2991243 What exactly are you asking? Do you want the same stream of random numbers to be generated per thread?

Comment: @rayryeng. I'm a bit confused about it. We need same random numbers for every optimization algorithm in this case?

Comment: If you need the same stream of random numbers, just generate an array of random numbers before you go into the loop, and give each loop the same array. This will negate any necessity to make sure your random generation is synchronized. Also this doesn't make much sense. Why would you want the same set of random numbers anyway. Them being the same set defeats the whole "random" nature of it.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 agreed.  Follow that suggestion, OP.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 It **can** happen actually!... especially when you fork multiple processes in Python.  All processes will seed from the same random generator, and so each process will generate the same stream of numbers... as such, it is customary to reseed the random generator with some value based on the process ID for each forked process before proceeding.

Comment: @ rayryeng. What is default structure of random numbers in MATLAB? we have same initial random numbers? We should edit question code to generate new random numbers in worker?

Comment: @rayryeng I have no doubt that this can happen. I know that when you start say `Random` in java or MATLAB it always starts from the same seed, unless you tell it otherwise. However, doing this just seems unnecessary for this specific problem. If you are trying to run an optimization, wouldn't you want truly different random seeds?

Comment: @user2991243 Please lessen the number of question marks. We have no idea what is a statement and what is a question.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 yes I agree with that. Should be truly random!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are asking, maybe not, but if you want different seeds for each loop you can seed the random number generator with a time stamp or something like that. This will make sure that each loop has a different seed and therefor a different set of random numbers

```
nLoops = 10
parfor ii = 1:nLoops
     timeVals = strsplit(sprintf('%.9f',now),'.')
     rng(str2double(timeVals{2}))
     % do some stuff
end
```

Or you can use MATLAB's built in shuffle function for `rng`

```
nLoops = 10
parfor ii = 1:nLoops
     rng('shuffle')
     % do some stuff
end
```

If you don't want it to be random in every loops, just create an array before you go into the loops, of whatever size you need, and have each loop access this same information. It is highly recommended that none of the loops edit anything about this array though

```
nLoops = 10;
randNums = rand(1,100)
parfor ii = 1:nLoops
     %do something with randNums(someNum)
end
```

Either option is relatively easy. If you are doing an optimization problem, you likely want to ensure that your random numbers are different though, that is kind of the point of optimization.

Comment: What is your idea about this? http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/control-random-number-streams.html. If we don't use `shuffle` or your first proposed procedure to have different random numbers in every worker and use my structure in question (without any new line of code,same as `for` loop) we have same random or different random numbers in every worker? We must use `rng(str2double(timeVals{2}))` or `shuffle`?

Comment: I honestly do not know. Why not run a test without your other code and see if each loop has identical random numbers. The code I provided gives a couples ways of guaranteeing constant identical random numbers as well as different ones? You decide how you want to use it. I can't provide any more help if you do not make it any more clear what you are actually asking me.